# What is the difference between pygame.event and pygame.fastevent?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

According to the `pygame.event` documentation, this function gets all the events from the queue.

> get events from the queue
> `get(eventtype=None)` -> Eventlist
> `get(eventtype=None, pump=True)` -> Eventlist
> This will get all the messages and remove them from the queue.

According to the `pygame.fastevent` documentation, this function gets all the events from the queue.

> get all events from the queue
> `get()` -> list of Events
> This will get all the messages and remove them from the queue.

#### So what's the difference?

I think the difference is about multithreading: `event` *"should be called from the main thread"* and `fastevent` is used in *"multithread environments"* - but I don't see any difference (in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66625655/getting-pygame-events-from-another-thread) case for example)

Comment: `pygame.fastevent` should behave the similarly to `pygame.event`. It's just a different implementation. `pygame.fastevent` is a wrapper for Bob Pendleton's fastevent library. Perhaps someone can provide more resources on Bob Pendleton's. However, the real question here is whether you want to handle the UI events in different threads. This seems like a bad design in your application.

Comment: You should make that the answer.  It's good speech.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Right. First, the answer to "What is the difference between `event` and `fastevent`" isn't quite clear for me (I think "wrapper for Bob's library" doesn't clearly explain the difference) - and the answer should be a technical explanation about how do `event` and `fastevent` function (= why was `fastevent` created if `event` already existed?)

Comment: Secondly, the sentences which link to multithreading are kinda way to show what I think would explain the difference (and my opinion about that: "`fastevent` does not work differently in terms of multithreading - or I don't use it correctly") -- So I will remove this part of the question, or shrink it into one sentence.

Comment: Everything you need to know you can find [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20080209034714/http://gameprogrammer.com/fastevents/fastevents1.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea behind `fastevent` was to remove some limitation in SDL's event handling code to be able to process more than 12,700 events per second.

You can still find the original documentation [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20080209034714/http://gameprogrammer.com/fastevents/fastevents1.html) and [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20080302114011/http://gameprogrammer.com/fastevents/fastevents2.html). A few quotes:

> Digging through the SDL_WaitEvent() code is when I got my nose rubbed in the fact that SDL is designed to work on operating systems that do not support threads. SDL_WaitEvent waits for events to arrive in the queue the simplest way possible, it uses SDL_Delay() to wait for 10 milliseconds and then checks to see if there are any events waiting. Checking the queue 100 times per second and possibly polling tor input events 100 times per second is great for single threaded games and it gives you the same results whether you OS supports threads or not.
> ...

> To figure out how fast the test should run I looked at the SDL event code and saw that the queue can hold at most 127 items and since SDL_WaitEvent() looks at the queue 100 times per second we know that SDL_WaitEvent() can not remove more than (127 * 100) = 12,700 events/second and you can't push more than 12,700 events into the queue in a second.
> ...

> Because I would like to use the same library for both the client and the server I wanted to see if I could make this code run a little faster.
> ...

> The next step was to write my own version of SDL_WaitEvent() and use a semaphore and a condition variable to control access to the event queue. A semaphore is a simple mutual exclusion operator also known as a mutex. A mutex is used by threads to keep more that one thread from touching a variable or running a section of code at the same time. Having more than one thread changing the same data at the same time leads to horrible bugs that are hard to find. In this case I needed a mutex to keep the contents of the queue consistent. A condition variable is just a way for one thread to let other threads know that something has happened. One or more threads can wait on a condition, and when another thread signals that the condition has occurred the waiting threads wake up an go about their business.
> ...

> When I tested that code I found that it got the SDL events and it was able to push over 30,000 events per second from my event pushing thread to the main SDL thread. I believe that the speed I'm seeing is only limited by the speed of my test machine, and not by anything in my code or in SDL. ...

Note that this does not remove the limition that the event handling functions must be
called from the main SDL thread. But it allows you to post events safely from other threads.

Comment: Thank you, it really helps me - In conclusion, `fastevent` is faster than `event` and it allows to post events from a thread and get them quickly in another thread. But the events can only be called from the main thread (for the moment).

Comment: But unless you want to use the SDL event system for ten 10,000s of events per second, don't bother with fastevent. This and also the fact Python's threading is limited by the GIL.